# Salesforce Classic Reports : I need to be able to create a field which subtracts value of one cell from the previous cell and display the difference

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Salesforce Classic Reports : I need to be able to create a field which subtracts value of one cell from the previous cell and display the difference. Basically, these are two revenue fields, say Jan FY2018 and Jan FY2019, I want a new column which displays the difference in revenues between them.

Can this be done through custom summary formula ? If so, please advise how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the custom Summary field by using one unique field(like Auto Number) and grouping is done with that field so for all the record that field has a different value. So you can show the difference between two fields on the Summary Level.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sandbox on Summer'19 release preview? If not - wait till weekend, your production & remaining sandboxes will probably be upgraded to Summer on [weekend of June 14-15](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/04/summer-19-sandbox-preview.html).

There's a beta feature that might do exactly what you want: [Row-level formulas in reports](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_row_level_formulas.htm). It's in **Lightning Experience only** and you need to enable something in Setup first. So move to Lightning? or wait, maybe next release it'll become Generally Available feature...